# Unable to install MSWin32-x64-multi-thread perl in Windows

Tags: perl

I downloded the strayberry perl using http://strawberryperl.com/download/5.30.2.1/strawberry-perl-5.30.2.1-64bit.msi and installed it in my windows 10 machine.

But, perl gets installed as part of cygwin. I want to install MSWin32-x64-multi-thread perl in Windows

This is the output of perl -v command

```
perl -v

This is perl 5, version 30, subversion 2 (v5.30.2) built for x86_64-cygwin-threads-multi
(with 7 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)

Copyright 1987-2020, Larry Wall

Perl may be copied only under the terms of either the Artistic License or the
GNU General Public License, which may be found in the Perl 5 source kit.

Complete documentation for Perl, including FAQ lists, should be found on
this system using "man perl" or "perldoc perl".  If you have access to the
Internet, point your browser at http://www.perl.org/, the Perl Home Page.
```

Can anyone help to get MSWin32-x64-multi-thread perl in Windows ?

Comment: Where did you type `perl`?

Comment: @ikegami, in the windows command terminal

Comment: Adjust your PATH so SP's dir is found before Cygwin's (or provide the full path to `perl.exe`)

Comment: Thanks @ikegami . Your suggestion worked for me . I am really grateful for your help :)